How to import library aar file in android studio
aar file
I have a project in which I want to include a library that is available as an aar file. What you see in the image is that I need to import these libraries into my project. I searched for many ways on the internet but none of the ones I found worked for me. Any help to achieve this and to be recognized? Thank you very much.

The image you mentioned does not exist on the question page. On the other hand, you should share what you tried or the simplified version of your "build.gradle" file for people answer correctly.

To include an AAR file in your Android project, follow these steps:
1. Place the AAR File: Copy the .aar file into the libs directory of your project. If libs doesn’t exist, create it inside the app module.

Modify build.gradle (app module):
dependencies {
    implementation files('libs/your-library.aar')
}


Sync the Project: Click "Sync Now" in Android Studio to apply the changes.

Include Repositories (if needed): Sometimes AAR files depend on other libraries. Make sure to include any necessary repositories in your build.gradle file.


After these steps, the library should be recognized in your project.

In my app I did as @Subhan and it worked. Then to reduce the size of the app I copied the necessary part of the source code directly into the project.
